# How to detect input types when binding event to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to bind an event to a parent instead of each child.
I can successfully test for SELECT, TEXTAREA and A. How to I test for input[type='text']?

```
$('form').bind('focusin', function(e) {
    var target = e.target, // e.target grabs the node that triggered the event.
        $target = $(target);  // wraps the node in a jQuery object
    if (target.nodeName === 'SELECT' | target.nodeName === 'TEXTAREA' | target.nodeName === 'A') {
        alert('hi');
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note: from jQuery 1.7, use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `delegate()`**

---

Using [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) sounds the easiest and most fitting to me.

```
$('form').delegate('textarea, select, a, input[type="text"]', 'focusin', function () {
  alert('hu');
  //do stuff
});
```

Actually it does just what you asked for. The event itself is attached to `form` and checks whether the `target` matches the selector given.

[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/ojegu4/2/)

*No need to reinvent the wheel.*

Answer (score 2):

Might I recommend changing your code to something like this:

```
$('form').bind('focusin', function(e) {
    var $target = $(this); // wraps the node in a jQuery object
    if ($target.is('select') || $target.is('textarea') || $target.is('a') || $target.is('input[type="text"]') {
        alert('hi');
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the `:input` selector to select all form elements:

```
$target.is(':input')
```

http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($target.attr('type')=='text') {
```

Comment: `target` was the DOM node, `$target` was the jQuery element. You would need to do `$target.attr`.